# What is the alternative of pytorch module.register_parameter(name, param) in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to convert some pytorch code to tensorflow. In the pytorch code they are adding some extra parameter on every module of a model using `module.register_parameter(name, param)`. How can i covert this part of code on tensorflow?

Sample code on below:

```
for module_name, module in self.model.named_modules():
    module.register_parameter(name, new_parameter)
```

Comment: I found out that i can use `layer.add_weight()` to add a new variable to a layer.

Comment: Do you know how to call a registered parameter in TensorFlow, like the below code in PyTorch? Thanks
`>>> module.register_parameter(name, new_parameter)
>>> module.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variable) is the equivalent of `nn.Parameter` in PyTorch. `tf.Variable` is mainly used to store model parameters since their values are constantly updated during training.

To use a tensor as a new model parameter, you need to convert it to `tf.Variable`. You can check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variable) how to create variables from tensors.

If you want to add a model parameter in TensorFlow inside the model itself, you could simply create a variable inside the model class and it will be automatically registered as a model parameter by TensorFlow.

If you want to add a `tf.Variable` *externally* to a model as a model parameter, you could manually add it to the [trainable_weights](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#attributes) attribute of `tf.keras.layers.Layer` by *extending* it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46570010/16424700) -

```
model.layers[-1].trainable_weights.extend([new_parameter])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out that i can use `layer.add_weight()` to add a new variable to a layer. Is this equivalent to `module.register_parameter()` on pytorch?

Comment: It seems you didn't find the answer you were looking for but yet the answer is accepted. Is that correct ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan I don't remember exactly, I worked on this problem a long time ago. But I think this answer was helpful for finding the solution, that's why I accepted it.